# Procedure to integrate AmCharts with OctoberCMS(Laravel) Pages

Tags: php, json, ajax, amcharts, octobercms

Can somebody share the knowledge to integrate Amchart in a page in OctoberCMS (laravel framework).

I am using OctoberCMS to build a web application. Their ajax documentation is different with the one in AMCharts.

I tried to figure out, but failed.

- [OctoberCMS documentaiton](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/ajax).
- [Amchart Documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/using-data-loader-to-connect-charts-to-mysql-data-base/).

It would be helpful if you can demonstrate with a sample project in GitHub.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use the dataLoader plugin for data retrieved through AJAX for AmCharts if it doesn't fit your purposes. You can make your ajax request and update the chart's dataProvider variable after the makeChart call (or tie your ajax request's success callback to create the chart with your returned data). It would be more helpful if you showed what you did so far so that folks like myself who aren't familiar with laravel/octobercms can have a starting point to spin up an example for you.